# How do I mock dependencies to return specific data?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

Coming from Moq in C# where you can do the following:

```
someMock
    .Setup(toBeMocked => toBeMocked.MockedMethod(It.IsAny<Something>()))
    .Returns(something);
```

Then in the unit test when I call

```
toBeMocked.MockedMethod()
```

It returns `something`. How do I do this with sinonjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinon works a bit differently than Moq, largely because C# is a much different language than JS. Moq creates sub-classes to inject fake methods, while sinon is able to inject them by assigning them directly onto objects.

Most basic pattern would be, assuming `toBeMocked` is an object with an instance method `MockedMethod`:

```
sinon.stub(toBeMocked, 'MockedMethod').returns(something);
```

This assigns the stub method to the `MockedMethod` property of the `toBeMocked` object. As such, it only affects that object, even if `MockedMethod` is a prototype method.

If you want to replace a method for all instances of a constructor, you can do that instead. Assuming `MockedClass` is the constructor you used to create the `toBeMocked` object, it'd look like this:

```
sinon.stub(MockedClass.prototype, 'MockedMethod').returns(something);
```

Then later in your teardown code:

```
MockedClass.prototype.MockedMethod.restore();
```

You need to restore it like this because that prototype is not created anew between tests, so your stub will pollute your other test code if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.2/stubs/ :

```
const fakeMethod = () => something;
const stub = sinon.stub(toBeMocked , 'MockedMethod');
stub.callsFake(fakeMethod);
```

UPDATE : example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9baurhew/)

Comment: This isn't how sinon's api works. `sinon.stub()` creates an anonymous stub function. Calling an anonymous stub like that on your third line won't do anything to the `toBeMocked` object.

Comment: There's also a streamlined api for making a stub return something, since it is such a common operation. Looks like this: `sinon.stub(toBeMocked, 'MockedMethod').returns(something);`

Comment: My bad, the param should have been passed to the constructor. But this solution work and does what OP is asking. Check the example fiddle in the updated answer

Comment: +1 for the callsFake() method, However @sripberger solution is cleaner if the goal is to just return something specific.